# Problem to update firmware using bootloader to PIC18F4550

Tags: pic, usb, usb-device, bootloader

I followed the documentation on the [Diolan's web site](http://usb-pic.org/usb-pic-bootloader) . I changed the project to be programmed to an PIC18F4550 and not a PIC18F4455 as it was originally written.

The compilation succeed and I was able to program the bootloader into the PIC18F4550's flash. I used PIckit3 and MPLABV8 to do it.

I did not encrypt my application using the encoder, I just tried to write it to memory without encrypt it. So, I copied and paste my .hex file application to the bin folder where the fw_update is. I opened the console and typed:

fw_update -e -w -v -vid 0x04D8 -pid 0xFF04 -ix example.hex

The followed message appears:

> U2IO flash erasing: FAILED.
>
> Device is not found.
>
> Operation aborted.

Does someone have some advice or tip of what it is happening ?

**OBSERVATION:**
My Windows 10 is not recognizing my USB device, neither before nor after the bootloader programming. It always inform: "USB device not recognized".

Below is picture of the schematic of my device:

[image]

**[Edited]**

Good observation, I saw at the datasheet that minimum value of CUSB is 220nF and there is no maximum and typical values.The hardware was not made by me, but I put the capacitor of 470nF, based on the [PICDEM™ FS USB DEMONSTRATION BOARD](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/51526C.pdf) of microchip. The Windowa 10 stopped to inform that the device was not connected, but at the device manager it is still with a yellow exclamation(But this time in HID USB). The error mentioned before still happens.

So, I did the following changes on the bootloder code:

In source files where was originally #include "P18F4455.INC" I changed to #include "P18F4550.INC"

On the Header files, I remove "P18F4455.INC" and put "P18F4550.INC instead that I downloaded from [here](https://class.ece.uw.edu/475/peckol/code/Microchip/microchipExamples/mpasm/P18F4550.INC).

My application code is edited on the project by its configuration bits this way:

CPU System Clock Postscaler was:
[OSC1/OSC2 Src:/4][96 MHz PLL Src: /6]

Power Up Timer: Enabled

The others I left default. And this configuration works when I run my  application without the bootloader.

But, when I will compiled the bootloader, I did not configure the configuration bits, the checkbox "Configuration Bits set in code" is selected as is said in the [documents](http://usb-pic.org/bootloader-compilation).

I found on the bootloader's file usb_desc.inc that :

```
#ifndef BOOTLOADER_VID
#define BOOTLOADER_VID  0x0000      ; MUST BE VALID Vendor ID
#endif
#ifndef BOOTLOADER_PID
#define BOOTLOADER_PID  0x0000      ; MUST BE VALID Product ID
#endif
```

So I changed my command line in the prompt to:

```
fw_update -e -w -v -vid 0x0000 -pid 0x0000 -ix principal.hex
```

But it still not working.

Comment: What drivers are you using? It sort of looks like you're missing drivers.

Comment: I don't know, do I need a specific driver?

Comment: @vini_i This boot loader uses the built-in HID drivers.

Answer (score 1):

See the below section of the data sheet- there may be other things wrong (the clock has to be correct) but it certainly won’t work without the cap on Vusb.

> 17.2.2.8 Internal Regulator
>   The PIC18FX455/X550 devices have a built-in 3.3V regulator to provide power to the internal transceiver and provide a source for the internal/external pull-ups. An external 220 nF (±20%) capacitor is required for stability.

Comment: Good observation. On the datasheet the minimum value of CUSB is 220nF and there is no maximum values.The hardware was not made by me, but I put the capacitor of 470nF, based on the PICDEM™ FS USB DEMONSTRATION BOARD. After that, the Windows 10 stopped to inform that the device was not connected, but at the device manager it is still with a yellow exclamation and the error mentioned before, when I tried to update firmware by usb, still happens. I will edited my question, I will put at the end, [edited] the modifications that I did on the bootloader project after the bootloader not working